# $T_2$ closed under intersections?

Tags: general-topology

Is the following true:

Suppose we have a collection of $T_2$ topologies on an infinite set $X$.

Is the intersection also $T_2$, or it doesn't have to be ?

Comment: The notion of intersecting a collection of $T_2$ topologies requires clarification.  Even if we assume a common underlying set, the possible $T_2$ topologies on an infinite set can be wildly different.  (On a finite set of course a $T_2$ topology will be discrete.)

Comment: Suppose that X is infinite.

Comment: By intersection do you mean $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$ is the topology generated by $\{U_1\cap U_2 : U_1\in \tau _1, U_2\in \tau_2\}$?

Comment: we know that that intersection of topologies is a topology so is it true that intersection of T_2 is T_2 ?

Comment: @JohnMa suppose for if we assume it is finite intersection of topologies suppose that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ is $T_2$ is $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$ $T_2$?

Comment: I am asking for the definition, is what I wrote you have in mind?

Comment: yeah the topology of $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$ will be the one generated by that basis.

Comment: @bof: Yes, I am just clarifying the definition the OP is using. If $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$ is just what I wrote (see my previous comment), then it seems trivial that the "intersection" has to be $T_2$.

Comment: @JohnMa: The OP is asking about the intersection of families of open sets, i.e. the sets open in all the collected topologies.

Comment: @bof: I completely agree with you, but it seems the OP is confused: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488240/t-2-closed-under-intersections#comment3031395_1488240) comment.

Comment: Yes I was confused

Comment: @bof: I cannot tell, but I did not see the OP answer the question of hardmath (the first comment), so I kind of "force" the OP to clarify (this is good for the OP or for anyone trying to learn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let 
$$\tau_1=\{U\subseteq\mathbb N:1\notin U\text{ or }|\mathbb N\setminus U|\lt\aleph_0\},$$
$$\tau_2=\{U\subseteq\mathbb N:2\notin U\text{ or }|\mathbb N\setminus U|\lt\aleph_0\}.$$
Then $\tau_1,\tau_2$ are T$_2$ topologies on $\mathbb N$, but the topology $\tau_1\cap\tau_2$ is not T$_2.$

Comment: why is $\tau_i$ , $T_2$ and why is the intersection not $T_2$?

Comment: Considering the sets common to both topologies, the intersection does not separate $1,2$,